# How to keep track of working directory in FUSE

Tags: c, fuse

So I am implementing a filesystem FUSE. I would like to know in which directory I am located when calling a function (specifically "mkdir"). Is there a way to know that? Or a way to keep track of directories when the user uses the "cd" command? The "getcwd" function always returns the root directory.

Comment: The FUSE API doesn't include any way to know the user's current directory.  I think you'd need to track that in your user space application.

Comment: @GandhiGandhi I just dont see how one would do that. I would have to know when the user calls the "cd" command then, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libfuse deamon is operating as root, and not in the context of the user operating on the mounted filesystem. This is why `getcwd` in your fuse code always returns the root directory. However, you do have access to some of the calling user's attributes, in particular their PID number, with `fuse_get_context()->pid` (see [linux how to intercept unauthorized process access to the file,base with FUSE( cryfs or gocryptfs )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330891/linux-how-to-intercept-unauthorized-process-access-to-the-file-base-with-fuse-c/))

Using the PID you can fetch the user's current directory by calling `readlink()` on `/proc/$pid/cwd` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509420/get-working-directory-of-logged-in-users)

Comment: Thank you. I kind of understand and have managed to use readlink() from the terminal. But I'm a little slow witted it seems. So may I ask how one would use it from inside a function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525668/how-to-implement-readlink-to-find-the-path