Linux Permission Denied
I clone the target directory and create 4 users on Linux with usernames according to the contents of the folder in the target directory.
User    Folder
andi    andi
budi    budi
cony    cony
deni    deni

Folder ownership table
The task is to make it so that each user can't add, change, or delete folders or files in folders they don't own. All the files inside of a folder will be encoded if accessed by a user who is not the owner of that folder (using Base64 encoding). On the contrary, all files will be decoded if they are accessed by the user who owns that folder.
So my code is like this:
#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 28
#include <fuse.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

static const char *target_dir = "/mnt/d/task-2/target";
static const char base64_table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

char *get_current_user() {
    uid_t uid = geteuid();
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(uid);
    if (pw) {
        return pw->pw_name;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void base64_encode(const unsigned char *src, size_t len, char *out) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len;) {
        uint32_t octet_a = i < len ? (unsigned char)src[i++] : 0;
        uint32_t octet_b = i < len ? (unsigned char)src[i++] : 0;
        uint32_t octet_c = i < len ? (unsigned char)src[i++] : 0;

        uint32_t triple = (octet_a << 0x10) + (octet_b << 0x08) + octet_c;

        out[j++] = base64_table[(triple >> 3 * 6) & 0x3F];
        out[j++] = base64_table[(triple >> 2 * 6) & 0x3F];
        out[j++] = base64_table[(triple >> 1 * 6) & 0x3F];
        out[j++] = base64_table[(triple >> 0 * 6) & 0x3F];
    }
    for (int pad = len % 3; pad && pad < 3; pad++) {
        out[--j] = '=';
    }
    out[j] = '\0';
}

int base64_decode(const char *src, unsigned char *out, size_t *out_len) {
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    if (len % 4) return -1;

    size_t output_len = len / 4 * 3;
    if (src[len - 1] == '=') output_len--;
    if (src[len - 2] == '=') output_len--;

    *out_len = output_len;
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < len;) {
        uint32_t sextet_a = src[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : strchr(base64_table, src[i++]) - base64_table;
        uint32_t sextet_b = src[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : strchr(base64_table, src[i++]) - base64_table;
        uint32_t sextet_c = src[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : strchr(base64_table, src[i++]) - base64_table;
        uint32_t sextet_d = src[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : strchr(base64_table, src[i++]) - base64_table;

        uint32_t triple = (sextet_a << 3 * 6) + (sextet_b << 2 * 6) + (sextet_c << 1 * 6) + (sextet_d << 0 * 6);

        if (j < output_len) out[j++] = (triple >> 2 * 8) & 0xFF;
        if (j < output_len) out[j++] = (triple >> 1 * 8) & 0xFF;
        if (j < output_len) out[j++] = (triple >> 0 * 8) & 0xFF;
    }
    return 0;
}

int check_ownership(const char *path, const char *current_user) {
    const char *last_slash = strrchr(path, '/');
    if (last_slash == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    const char *subfolder_name = last_slash + 1;

    if (strcmp(subfolder_name, current_user) == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}



static int xmp_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf) {
    int res;
    char fpath[1000];
    sprintf(fpath, "%s%s", target_dir, path);
    res = lstat(fpath, stbuf);
    if (res == -1) return -errno;
    return 0;
}

// Membaca direktori
static int xmp_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    char fpath[1000];
    if (strcmp(path, "/") == 0) {
        path = target_dir;
        sprintf(fpath, "%s", path);
    } else {
        sprintf(fpath, "%s%s", target_dir, path);
    }

    int res = 0;
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *de;
    (void) offset;
    (void) fi;
    dp = opendir(fpath);
    if (dp == NULL) return -errno;
    while ((de = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        struct stat st;
        memset(&st, 0, sizeof(st));
        st.st_ino = de->d_ino;
        st.st_mode = de->d_type << 12;
        res = (filler(buf, de->d_name, &st, 0));
        if (res != 0) break;
    }
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}

static int xmp_read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    char fpath[1000];
    sprintf(fpath, "%s%s", target_dir, path);

    int fd;
    int res;
    (void) fi;

    fd = open(fpath, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) return -errno;

    res = pread(fd, buf, size, offset);
    if (res == -1) res = -errno;
    close(fd);

    if (!check_ownership(path, get_current_user())) {
        char encoded_buf[4 * ((res + 2) / 3) + 1];
        base64_encode((unsigned char *)buf, res, encoded_buf);
        memcpy(buf, encoded_buf, strlen(encoded_buf) + 1);
        res = strlen(buf);
    }
    return res;
}

static int xmp_write(const char *path, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    char fpath[1000];
    sprintf(fpath, "%s%s", target_dir, path);

    if (!check_ownership(path, get_current_user())) {
        return -EACCES;
    }

    int fd;
    int res;
    (void) fi;
    fd = open(fpath, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1) return -errno;

    res = pwrite(fd, buf, size, offset);
    if (res == -1) res = -errno;
    close(fd);
    return res;
}

// Membuat file node
static int xmp_mknod(const char *path, mode_t mode, dev_t rdev) {
    char fpath[1000];
    sprintf(fpath, "%s%s", target_dir, path);

    // Jika bukan pemilik folder, tolak akses
    if (!check_ownership(path, get_current_user())) {
        return -EACCES;
    }

    int res;
    if (S_ISREG(mode)) {
        res = open(fpath, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY, mode);
        if (res >= 0) res = close(res);
    } else if (S_ISFIFO(mode)) {
        res = mkfifo(fpath, mode);
    } else {
        res = mknod(fpath, mode, rdev);
    }
    if (res == -1) return -errno;
    return 0;
}

// Membuat direktori
static int xmp_mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode) {
    char fpath[1000];
    sprintf(fpath, "%s%s", target_dir, path);

    // Jika bukan pemilik folder, tolak akses
    if (!check_ownership(path, get_current_user())) {
        return -EACCES;
    }

    int res = mkdir(fpath, mode);
    if (res == -1) return -errno;
    return 0;
}

// Menghapus file
static int xmp_unlink(const char *path) {
    char fpath[1000];
    sprintf(fpath, "%s%s", target_dir, path);

    // Jika bukan pemilik folder, tolak akses
    if (!check_ownership(path, get_current_user())) {
        return -EACCES;
    }

    int res = unlink(fpath);
    if (res == -1) return -errno;
    return 0;
}

// Menghapus direktori
static int xmp_rmdir(const char *path) {
    char fpath[1000];
    sprintf(fpath, "%s%s", target_dir, path);

    // Jika bukan pemilik folder, tolak akses
    if (!check_ownership(path, get_current_user())) {
        return -EACCES;
    }

    int res = rmdir(fpath);
    if (res == -1) return -errno;
    return 0;
}

static int xmp_rename(const char *from, const char *to) {
    char ffrom[1000], fto[1000];
    sprintf(ffrom, "%s%s", target_dir, from);
    sprintf(fto, "%s%s", target_dir, to);

    // Jika bukan pemilik folder, tolak akses
    if (!check_ownership(from, get_current_user()) || !check_ownership(to, get_current_user())) {
        return -EACCES;
    }

    int res = rename(ffrom, fto);
    if (res == -1) return -errno;
    return 0;
}

static struct fuse_operations xmp_oper = {
    .getattr    = xmp_getattr,
    .readdir    = xmp_readdir,
    .read       = xmp_read,
    .write      = xmp_write,
    .mknod      = xmp_mknod,
    .mkdir      = xmp_mkdir,
    .unlink     = xmp_unlink,
    .rmdir      = xmp_rmdir,
    .rename     = xmp_rename,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    umask(0);
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &xmp_oper, NULL);
}

Then I run with:
./fuse -o allow_other /mnt/d/task-2/mount

I run that in task-2 directory because the fuse.c is in my task-2 directory.
Then I do cd mount and su andi, and cd andi.
Then I do mkdir test but it says:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied

Why? According to the check_ownership() the subfolder_name is andi because right now I'm in directory called andi and the user I login is now andi too, it should given me access to mkdir in the andi directory.

Just a cursory look... When trying to create a subdir Y under parent dir X (that exists) (i.e. X/Y), the uid must have write permission to X. I think in xmp_mkdir you have the permission check reversed and are checking for permission on Y instead of X???

I would guess the problem is in your get_current_user. Did you verify it is indeed recognizing the user?
As much as I know the fuse process runs as root (uid 0). To get the current user who is actually doing the current file operation, you need to use fuse_get_context()->uid.
For more about that, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64331365/4198124.
